# Accessing image dimensions on an ImageField in a Django template?

Tags: django, image, dimensions

I have `ImageField` in my model and I'm able to display the image in a template. However, how do I retrieve the image's height and width?

Comment: Here is one of the solution by @Nifled, hope that helps - [ImageField image_width and image_height auto fill for existing database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064339/imagefield-image-width-and-image-height-auto-fill-for-existing-database)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

See the documentation for [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField).

> In addition to the special attributes
>   that are available for FileField, an
>   ImageField also has height and width
>   attributes.

So just do the following:

```
<img src="{{ image.url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}"/>
```

Comment: hmmm.. it doesn't work on my end.

`{% with post.postimage_set.all as image %}`

`<a href="{{ image.get_image_url }}"><img src="{{ image.get_image_url }}" title="{{ image.title }}" alt="{{ alt }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" /></a>`

`{% endwith %}`

Comment: @bonbon.langes responding 10 years later, but your example wouldn't work because you are trying to get width and height from a queryset, not a single image object.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, for the `width` and `height` fields to work, I need to set the [`width_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField.width_field) and [`height_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField.height_field) of the `ImageField`

E.g.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(width_field='image_width', height_field='image_height')
    image_width = models.IntegerField()
    image_height = models.IntegerField()
```