# ImageField image_width and image_height auto fill for existing database?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have an existing database table with an `ImageField` that already has a bunch of existing registries. I want to add the `image_width` and `image_height` on my model but I need something to auto-fill the existing tables with.

```
class ItemImage(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path, width_field='image_width', height_field='image_height')
    image_width = models.IntegerField()
    image_height = models.IntegerField()
```

I read on the docs that both `image_width` and `image_height` get generated automatically when on `save()`, but the existing images have already been saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I've found a solution! It's a weird one, but it works. I set both `image_width` and `image_height` to default to `0` and did a standard migration on dev.

Of course, you would suppose all the existing images be set to `0` height and width, but when I try to access these attributes, for example, in their detail view, I get access to the correct height and width values of the original image (an existing image that was saved before I did the migration).

If someone can explain this I'd be grateful.